# Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm getting nuts with this error. Please have an EXACT look at the error message! It's "**SS**ErrorDomain" NOT "SK..." in combination with code=0. I wasn't able find anybody with the same issue anywhere on the net so far. People seem to have either **SS**ErrorDomain with code=**2** or **SK**ErrorDomain with code=**0**. My combination was nowhere described and nothing helped so far.

Ok, here's what I try: App is working fine without in-App since 1st January it is available on the store. Now I've added In-App purchases to my App. I try to test them but all I get is the above error. It does not even try to ask me for a test user or anything.

I'm absolutely sure, I'm logged out of the store, working on a real device and did all the other tests (many times) that I could find on the net. Nothing! Still "Cannot connect..."

I've checked all things described here [Ray Wenderlichs In-App Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial). I've even created a new App from scratch with his tutorial. Same Problem. Waiting for several days didn't help either.

I've done the things described here [Cannot connect to iTunes in Baker Factory](http://www.bakerframework.com/cannot-connect-to-itunes/). You can guess the result.

Here's some code. Just the start which is called in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
internal class InApp : NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
private var request: SKProductsRequest!

// Start communication with Apple Store to retrieve list of available products
internal func start() {
    if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("InAppProducts", withExtension: "plist") {
        if let productIds = NSArray(contentsOfURL: url) {
            NSLog("InApp: Product-Id \(productIds)")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
            request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(arrayLiteral: productIds))
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
            NSLog("InApp: request started")
       }
    }
}
```

The log prints the two product id's, read from plist, correctly. The log also shows the "request started". After that it calls directly the error routine:

```
    internal func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("ERROR: decription: \(error!.description), reason: \(error!.localizedFailureReason), options: \(error!.localizedRecoveryOptions), suggestion: \(error!.localizedRecoverySuggestion)")
}
```

I'm using Xcode 6.3 and an iPhone 6 with iOS 8.3. GameCenter iAdBanner and all other features work perfectly.

Any any any suggestions, where I could look at and what I could do, are **highly** welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found it. It's actually a duplicate of this one: [Swift Cannot connect to iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470565/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-to-get-in-app-purchase-listing).

Here's the code snippet I've changed:
OLD/WRONG:

```
            if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("InAppProducts", withExtension: "plist") {
            if let productIds = NSArray(contentsOfURL: url) {
                let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(arrayLiteral: productIds))
                request.delegate = self
                request.start()
                return true
            }
        }
```

NEW/RIGHT:

```
            if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("InAppProducts", withExtension: "plist") {
            if let productIds = NSArray(contentsOfURL: url) {
                var set = Set<String>()
                for productId in productIds {
                    if let productId = productId as? String {set.insert(productId as String)}
                }
                log("InApp: Product-Id \(productIds) = \(set))")

                let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: set)
                request.delegate = self
                request.start()
                return true
            }
        }
```

Basically, I made a mistake in reading from the plist as it was stored in a set as one object, containing two strings. Now it is really a set of two Strings.

In the end a very "interesting" error message for not being able to init the request at all!