# App rejected for In app purchase error

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, rmstore

My app got rejected from app store with following reason:

> We found that your in-app purchase product(s) exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 10.2.
>
> Specifically, a purchase error message was displayed when we tapped the subscription in-app purchases on the Pro Membership screen.

[image]

All my products are getting fetched correctly from in app services.

On further debugging I found that I am receiving following error

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}

Error is resolved when I follow [this url](https://support.zinio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204210493-Error-Message-iTunes-ID-Purchase-Error-iOS-)

But my question is how can I take this case with the Apple review team?

Comment: Could you try installing the app on a new device if possible (one on which it has never been installed), then tapping the purchase button?

Comment: @Coder256: Thanks for writing. Yes I did tried it on a new iPhone 6 device with iOS 9.1 but the  behaviour is same.

Comment: The same as in it also had that error? Can you please update your answer with the code you used to trigger the purchase?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14356697/3507433.