# inapp purchase failed while app review

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have the following problem: I've added **in-app purchases** to my app, tested them as it is suggested by apple (I used both my own and sandbox accounts, using test flight distribution version) and everything works.
However, when these inapp purchases are being tested during app review by apple , the **SKPaymentTransaction** fails with error:

> code=0 "cannot connect to iTunes store.
>   UserInfo={NSLoalizedDesciption=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}"

what can cause this?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341382/cannot-connect-to-itunes-store-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: As I can see, all of these requirements are fulfilled, and by your link the problem appeared not only during review but at the development stage too. In my case everything works even with testflight version, but doesn't work only during review at apple .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have to wait a few hours before in-app purchases are available for buying in production (sandbox is different).**

I think Apple doesn't review apps in sandbox, so it may be expected behavior. Or maybe throwing an error on buying in-app purchase is part of the review process.

In my opinion, if everything was working in sandbox, you don't have to worry about production (I really think it's about the little delay).

Comment: Indeed, it started to work for apple reviews too. But it took not a few hours, but more than a week between creating of in-app purchases and the moment, when it started to work during review